# Group table data with rowspan

Tags: javascript, php, html, sql

[How My table currently looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2jyls.png)

I am want to have a side column using rowspan that has the pay period and groups dates in that pay period together. I want a supervisor to be able to  create a new pay period which generates an integer in the database and then the rowspan will group any data submitted during that pay period.

My current Table Code:

```
    <div class="table-responsive">  
      <table id="editable_table" class="table table-bordered table-striped" data-editable="true" data-buttons-toolbar=".toolbar" data-search="true"data-show-refresh="true" >
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Index</th>
                    <th>Employee ID</th>
                    <th>Username</th>
                    <th>Date</th>
                    <th>Time In</th>
                    <th>Time Out</th>
                    <th>Total Hours</th>
                    <th>Submit Status</th>
                    <th>Approved Status</th>
                    <th>Time Change</th>
                    <th>Edit</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <?php
                    while($row = $res->fetch()){
                        echo '
                        <tr>
                        <td>'.$row["id"].'</td>
                        <td>'.$row["user_id"].'</td>                    
                        <td>'.$row["name"].'</td>
                        <td>'.$row["submit_day"].'</td>
                        <td>'.$row["time_in"].'</td>
                        <td>'.$row["time_out"].'</td>
                        <td>'.$row["total_hours"].'</td>                                                
                        <td>'.$row["submit_status"].'</td>
                        <td  style="color:green;">'.$row["approve_status"].'</td>

                       <td>'.$row["change_request"].'</td>
                       <td><center><a id="editbtn" href="action.php?id='.$row["id"].'"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span></a></td>
                      </tr>';
                }
             ?>
        </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
```

Im not sure how I would use rowspan to collate the data to look something like this:
[Example table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A5KnM.png)

Comment: Did you get the answer you were looking for?

Comment: @AdamWhateverson Not necessarily, I want to have a supervisor click a button to generate a new int value in the database which specifies the pay period and so anytime submitted during this pay period will fall under the rowspan with correlated with that  period. Not sure if that makes sense, but if you need more explaining I can try to make it make more sense.

Comment: You need to change the way you ask the question initially because it sounds like you want to know how row span works not an entire interface.

Comment: @AdamWhateverson Question updated

Comment: I have updated my answer so that rowspan is not required as in my opinion, pre-calculating what the rowspan needs to be is overkill.  My solution allows you to directly output the code without storing code before outputting.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I am updating my answer as it was downgraded for unknown reasons that nobody will explain.

So here is my answer based on what I'd do and based on logic.

In short, don't try and do what you are going to in PHP because it will create too much extra work and complication in your loop code otherwise you will need to make pre-calculations to know the row span to set for the number of items in that period before outputting the items in that period.

Before I continue, maybe ask yourself the question "Why do I need to print the period only once when it changes and how does that help the end user? if at all?"

You aren't saving any space by trying to group them by period as you are still using a column so you *could* repeat the period in that column all the way down the page because if someone is scrolling down and the period is not in the left hand column they might have to scroll up to remember what period they were in.

If you wanted to avoid PHP pre-calculations and still do what you wanted to do you can print the period only when you know it's changed and then use CSS to format the table like so.

For example:

```
$lastPeriod="";
while($row = $mysqli->fetchassoc($res)){
    echo "<tr>";
    if($lastPeriod == $row["period"]){
        echo "<td>&nbsp;</td>";
    } else {
        echo "<td class='period'>$row[period]</td>";
    }
    // echo the rest of the cells in the row
    echo "</tr>";
    $lastPeriod = $row["period"];
}
```

```css
table{
border-collapse:collapse;
}
table tr th,
table tr td{
padding:5px;
border-color:#dddddd; /* Only have to set colour once this way*/
border-style:solid;
border-width:0px 0px 1px 0px;
}
table tr th{
background-color:#eeeeee;
}
table tr td:first-child{
border-width:0px;
}
table tr td.period{
  border-width:0px 0px 1px 0px !important;
  font-weight:bold;
 }
```

```html
<table>
<tr>
<th>Period</th>
<th>Name</th>
<th>Day</th>
<th>Options</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class='period'>September</td>
<td>John</td>
<td>01</td>
<td>-</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td></td>
<td>Mary</td>
<td>05</td>
<td>-</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td></td>
<td>Joe</td>
<td>06</td>
<td>-</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class='period'>October</td>
<td>John</td>
<td>22</td>
<td>-</td>
</tr>
</table>
```